# Specal characters drawn weird to image using PY2.7 and Pillow

Tags: python-2.7, python-imaging-library, special-characters

I'm trying to add text to an image using Pillow and the special Danish characters doesn't appear right.

I thought that it might be a font-problem since I read somewhere that it could be an issue but even when I specify a font I know is capable of showing the letters, they don't appear.

```
message="I want to add letters like ø and å"
image = Image.open('image.png')
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
font_name = ImageFont.truetype('C:/Windows/Fonts/micross.ttf', size=20)
draw.text((155,165),message, fill=color, font=font_name)
image.show()
```

Now, the letters are super weird and, as an example, the letter å becomes "Ã,". Anything obvious I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python 2 uses ASCII encoding by default. Either switch to python3 or add `u` before the string:

```
u"I want to add letters like ø and å"
```

Comment: Okay, cool. This does the trick for two of the lines, but the others are generated as a combination of two strings like:

    new_message=message1+message2

How do I specify unicode here?

Comment: It should be automatically turned to unicode.
>>> s1 = u'a'
>>> s2 = u'b'
>>> type(s1)
<type 'unicode'>
>>> type(s2)
<type 'unicode'>
>>> s = s1+s2
>>> type(s)
<type 'unicode'>

Comment: The problem is, that I use a tool to grab a random word from a list and save that as the string like:
    message=random.choice(list_of_words)
Can I convert the entire list to unicode?

Comment: Sure: >>> s = 's'
>>> unicode(s)
u's'
<- this converts single entry. You can call this on grabbing words.

Comment: Sorry, it won't work like this. How do you populate your `list_of_words`?